# Web application: Only authorized communication with server

Tags: security, web-applications, authorization, communication

For a web application I'm looking for means of communication that will only allow the web application to communicate with my server.
Since URLs of things are extractable from the JavaScript code, one could use the URLs directly for, say, a brute force attack on login data, or query if a particular user is already registered with the system, to give only a few examples.

I have the feeling that encrypting data client side and decrypting them server side won't work because any encryption, however sophisticated, on the client side will again be exposed to an attacker through JavaScript code. For per-form-authorization one could send a throw-away authorization key. But such key would again be obtainable and usable by an attacker, so what's the security gain?

So here's the actual question: How can I authorize only my application to talk to the server and reject direct calls?

Foot note: I have SSL, so transmission encryption is no concern. But that won't help against brute force attacks.

Answer (score 0):

one solution can be end point authentication. You can use mutual authentication in TLS/SSL. you can accomplish that using PSK variation also.